# VsCode matplotlib doesnt show figure window

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("Desktop\sudoku.jpg", 0)
img = np.float32(img)
plt.figure()
plt.plot()
plt.imshow(img), plt.axis("off")

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

code doesn't give error but figure window is not opening

Comment: Use `plt.show()` after `plt.imshow(img)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing cv2 and matplotlib. If you just want to display the image you can do it like so:

**Using cv2:**

```
import cv2
I = cv2.imread('path/to/img')
cv2.imshow('window_name', I)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

or you can use matplotlib by simply adding plt.show() at the end as @JeruLuke pointed out. Just remember that OpenCV reads the image as BGR and this would make the colors show up weird when you display the image. You can use `cv2.imread('path/to/image.jpg', COLOR_BGR2RGB)` if you are set on using matplotlib.